# Apply if function to identify the value of variable based on the value of another variable

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to identify the value of the variable in an R data frame conditioning on the value of another variable, but unable to do it. 
Basically, I am giving 3 different `Dose` of vaccine to three groups of animals (5 animal per group ( `Total` )) and recording results as `Protec` which means the number of protected animals in each group. From the `Protec`, I am calculating the proportion of protection (Protec/Total as `Prop` for each `Dose` group. For example

```
library(dplyr)
Dose=c(1,0.25,0.0625);Dose #Dose or Dilution
Protec=c(5,4,3);Protec
Total=c(rep(5,3));Total
df=as.data.frame(cbind(Dose,Protec,Total));df
df=df %>% mutate(Prop=Protec/Total);df
```

Question is, what is the log10 of minimum value of `Dose` for which `Prop==1`, which can be found using the following code

```
X0=log10(min(df$Dose[df$Prop1==1.0]));X0
```

The result should be X0=0

If the `Protec=c(5,5,3)`, the `Prop` becomes c(1.0,1.0,0.6) then the X0 should be -0.60206.
If the `Protec=c(5,5,5)`, the `Prop` becomes c(1.0,1.0,1.0), For which I want X0=0. 
if the `Protec=c(5,4,5)`, the `Prop` becomes c(1.0,0.8,1.0), then also I want X0=0 because I consider them as unordered and take the highest dose for calculating X0

I think it requires if function but the conditions for which I don't know how to write the code.

can someone explain how to do it in R?. thanking you in advance

Comment: Could you post your expected output? Can't quite follow this part : **However, in case of trend is like Prop2, Prop3, Prop4**

Comment: The Prop1 is equal to 1.0,0.8,0.6 for the doses 1.0, 0.25, 0.0625 and hence minimum value of dose equalling Prop1==1.0 is 1.0. Here there is a decreasing trend in Prop1, and hence the calculation is straight forward. If the trend in Prop is like 1.0,1.0,0.8, then the value of dose i get should be 0.25.However in case of other scenario, I want to get the minimum value of dose i.e ` dose==1.0`, even if there is trend like the one noticed in Prop2,Prop3,Prop4

Comment: @NelsonGon I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` to create apply the calculation on multiple columns that have column name starting with 'Protec'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
         mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Protec")), list(Prop = ~./Total))
```

Comment: I want to have the minimum value of dose for which the Prop is 1.0. For example the minimum value of dose for which Prop1==1.0  is 1.0. in case of minimum value of dose for which Prop2==1.0 is 0.0625. however, the trend is not decreasing and want to consider as not correct and want to consider the highest dose as the correct result. similarly the minimum value of dose for which Prop3, Prop4==1.0 is 0.0625, which is also want to consider as not correct and get the result as value of the highest dose.

Comment: @R.P.TamilSelvan  Can you update your post with the expected output.  It is not very clear

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear i think.